# Indexed singly linked list

Tags: c++

I want to create a singly linked list with. I already have an implementation that does not permit indexing on it. 
I would like to add this feature but I am not sure how to do that.

[image: Linked List]

So basically the head should have index "1". But I can't figure it out myself what am I supposed to do in If statement to increase the index by `1` each step.

```
void AddNode (int addData)
{
    nodePtr NewNode = new node;
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = NewNode;
        NewNode->index;
    }
    else
    {
        head = NewNode;
        NewNode->index = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The head should have index 0 if you want to match convention.

Comment: And you don't necessarily have to store the index with the nodes. I don't think I've ever written a list where the indices are stored with the elements. Indices only really need to be used while traversing the list, and in that case a for-loop (or whatever) manages them.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf thanks a lot, sir!

Comment: @KyleKhalaf What happens when you have two lists at the same time?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf you could make a `static std::vector<std::pair<pointer, int>>` to keep track of it... but is that a world you really want to live in? Also, now you have to reindex things when nodes get deleted, manage your static vector when lists go away...

Answer (score 3):

You mean for the ability to do something like get a linked list node via a get(index)?

Also, your head should not have index 1, it should be 0. This does not comply with standard practice of zero-based indexing.

A linked list does not technically have indexes nor should it store them. It seems like a linked list might not be the right data structure for what you are doing, however you can treat it like so with a loop like this (excuse if my c++ syntax is rusty)

```
int get(int index) {
  Node current = head;
  for (int x = 0; x < index; x++) {
    if (current->next == null) {
      //some sort of error handling for index out of bounds
    } else {
      current = current->next;
    }
  }
  return current->data
}
```

get(2) would return the 3rd element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

[Graph for the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suctI.png)
Why do you want to add it to the end of the list? Just simply add the new node to the front.

I don't think it is necessary to follow the order of 1,2,3.... Instead, you can do it reversely
Before you add a new node, you visit the head and find the index(i)of it. When you add the new one, the index of this one will be i+1.

Two advantages:
- It doses not change anything when you loop through this list.
- You know how many you have added into this list.

Answer (score 0):

So what you really want to do is to add the **ability** to index elements of a linked list.

- There is no need to actually store the index anywhere (as you don't really store the index of an `array/vector` element as the type and the address of the first element of the array is everything you need to retrieve the `i-th` element).
- The only information you want to keep is the length of the list since computing it is costly because you have to traverse the list from `head` to `tail` every time you need it. Once you have this information the `addNode` should only update the `size` of the list.

As you already know accessing the `i-th` elements of a linked list is also costly (compared to a vector), but it is easy to code.

Something like the following should work:

```
void get(Node* head, size_t pos) {
    while (head && pos--)
        head = head->next;
    return pos<=0 ? head : nullptr ;
}
```

It traverses the list from the `head` until  it either reaches the end (`head` is `nullptr`) or `pos` is `<=0`.
Once you are out of the loop if `pos>0` means that the list is shorter than `pos` otherwise you can return `head` (which will point to the `pos-th` element)